# Remove duplicates based on a column with unique index of shorter length

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `RU_sg1lib_MASTER` (
 `ID` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Title` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
 `VolumeInfo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Series` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Periodical` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Author` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Year` varchar(14) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Edition` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Publisher` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `City` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Pages` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `PagesInFile` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Language` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Topic` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Library` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Issue` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Identifier` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `ISSN` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `ASIN` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `UDC` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `LBC` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `DDC` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `LCC` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Doi` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Googlebookid` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `OpenLibraryID` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Commentary` varchar(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `DPI` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
 `Color` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Cleaned` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Orientation` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Paginated` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Scanned` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Bookmarked` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Searchable` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Filesize` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Extension` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `MD5` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Generic` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Visible` char(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Locator` varchar(733) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Local` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
 `TimeAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 13:00:00',
 `TimeLastModified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `Coverurl` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Tags` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `IdentifierWODash` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT '',
 `Zstatus_retrieve_TOC` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Zstatus_retrieve_classifybyoclc` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I know from a manual inspection of the data that the `Title` column contains many duplicates. So, I embarked on removing the duplicates. I did this by:

Step 1: Copy the table with data to another table (`temp`) using PHPMyadmin
Step 2: TRUNCATE TABLE `RU_sg1lib_MASTER`
Step 3: There was a Primary Key index on the `ID` column. So I removed it, and created a Primary Key (length 256) on the `Title`. The resultant indexes are:
PRIMARY KEY (`Title`(256)),
KEY `classifybyoclc_respcode` (`classifybyoclc_respcode`(256)),
KEY `classifybyoclc_calln_lcc` (`classifybyoclc_calln_lcc`),

Step 4: INSERT IGNORE INTO `RU_sg1lib_MASTER` SELECT * FROM `temp`

At that time, I did not have a complete knowledge about indexes (especially indexes with specified length). Lately, it occurred to me that because the `Title` index has specified length of 256, it might cause some values which are not entirely the same but which have the same initial characters to be mistaken as exact duplicates and hence removed.

Am I correct about this?

If yes, how can I remove duplicates accurately for this table which consists of 3+ million records?

Comment: *how can I remove duplicates accurately for this table which consists of 3+ million records?* You must definitely remove the duplicates with according DELETE statement, not copy your data from-and-back.

Comment: ```DELETE t1 FROM RU_sg1lib_MASTER t1 JOIN RU_sg1lib_MASTER t2 ON t1.title = t2.title AND t1.id > t2.id;```

Comment: ok @akina thank you. so am I correct about the mistaken duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct: If you specify `PRIMARY KEY (Title(256))` then the `Title` column must be unique in the first 256 characters and you would be eliminating rows whose `Title` column that were identical in those first 256 characters but differed in subsequent character positions. By the way, there was no need to change your primary key. You could have *attempted* to keep column `ID` as the primary key and instead define a UNIQUE INDEX for column `title` without specifying an explicit length. But that would have failed because of a restriction on the largest index size you can have, which for MySQL is 767 bytes (not characters) by default even for MySQL 8.

The maximum index length is 767 bytes (or 3072 for InnoDB tables that use DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED row format). Column `Title` specifies a collation of *utf8mb4_unicode_ci*, which means that a character can require up to 4 bytes to store and therefore the largest index you can have is is floor(767/4) or 191 characters (768 characters for InnoDB tables that use DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED row format). So if you have any `Title` column values whose length is greater than 191 (or 768), you cannot specify an index on this column for the full size. Otherwise, you could just redefine the column to be length 191 (or 768) and your problem is solved.

So assuming that you do have rows where the length of the `Title` column is greater than the maximum index size you can have, you need an alternate method to guarantee uniqueness since specifying a UNIQUE KEY is no longer an option. You could issue the DELETE statement as suggested by Akina.

But then the problem remains of ensuring that in the future no duplicate `Title` columns exists. This would require you to first query the table to see if there already exists a row with the given `Title` value when doing an insert or an update that modifies a `Title` column value. This could also be done automatically by defining AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE triggers. But since the `Title` column is unindexed, every row has to be read to determine whether there is uniqueness or not.